# What is the purpose of package.json~ and package.json.orig?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I understand what `package.json` is used for, but I also am seeing files named `package.json~` and `package.json.orig`. What is the purpose of these files, or are they just temporary copies that I can delete?

Comment: Where did it come from?

Comment: `*.orig` files come from Git during a merge.  I believe they are supposed to be temporary when no errors occur.  Not sure about `package.json~`.  Seems likely it's a temporary file, but can't find any confirmation of that.  Github seems to make it impossible to search the NPM repository for `package.json~` to see where the code is using it.

Comment: I am not sure where they come from, but they are old files i.e. three or more years old.

Comment: @Obromios since you mentioned those are old files, can you check the file metadata to see the author or if there's any relevant information? Those probably look like programmer-made files for backup, like when we do .env.prod for example.

Comment: package.json~ might be from emacs, if you used emacs to edit package.json. It generate an automatic file with a ~ ind the name.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that the package.json.orig files come about during an error in a `git merge` operation and can be deleted. The `package.json~` may well have been a typo.